# Manage External Storage Permission not clickable

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, android-external-storage

So, I am creating an app, with the goal of turning text to pdf, and saving it to the external storage. After running the app with no errors, I encountered a weird bug, the "Manage External Storage Permission" button was not clickable. After reading the stack overflow posts, it seems like I have wrote the proper functions, but all the examples were in activities, so the problem may be there

Any help?

```
class CreatePdfFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_create_pdf) {

private lateinit var binding: FragmentCreatePdfBinding
private val STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE: Int = 100

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = FragmentCreatePdfBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.btnToPdf.setOnClickListener {
        if (checkPermission()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: Permission already granted, create folder")
            savePdf()
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: Permission was not granted, request")
            requestPermission()
        }
    }
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.isNotEmpty()) {
            val write = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            val read = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            if (write && read) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: External Storage Permission granted")
                savePdf()
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: External Storage Permission denied...")
                toast("External Storage Permission denied...")
            }
        }
    }
}




private fun savePdf() {
    //create object of Document class
    val mDoc = Document()
    //pdf file name
    val mFileName = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(System.currentTimeMillis())
    //pdf file path
    val mFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + mFileName +".pdf"
    try {
        //create instance of PdfWriter class
        PdfWriter.getInstance(mDoc, FileOutputStream(mFilePath))

        //open the document for writing
        mDoc.open()

        //get text from EditText i.e. textEt
        val mText = binding.etPdfText.text.toString()

        //add author of the document (metadata)
        mDoc.addAuthor("Atif Pervaiz")

        //add paragraph to the document
        mDoc.add(Paragraph(mText))

        //close document
        mDoc.close()

        //show file saved message with file name and path
        toast("$mFileName.pdf\nis saved to\n$mFilePath")
    }
    catch (e: Exception){
        //if anything goes wrong causing exception, get and show exception message
        toast(e.message.toString())
    }

}

private val storageActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
    Log.d(TAG, "storageActivityResultLauncher: ")

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "storageActivityResultLauncher: ")
            savePdf()
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "storageActivityResultLauncher: Manage External Storage Permission is denied...")
            toast("Manage External Storage Permission is denied...")
        }
    } else {

    }
}


private fun requestPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "requestPermission: try")
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.action = Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION
            val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", this@CreatePdfFragment.requireActivity().packageName, null)
            intent.data = uri
            storageActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, "requestPermission: ", e)
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.action = Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION
            storageActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent)
        }
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@CreatePdfFragment.requireActivity(),
        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
        STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE)
    }
}

private fun checkPermission(): Boolean {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        Environment.isExternalStorageManager()
    } else {
        val write = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@CreatePdfFragment.requireActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        val read = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@CreatePdfFragment.requireActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        write == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && read == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
}


private fun toast(message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this@CreatePdfFragment.requireActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you see such a button?

Comment: `but all the examples were in activities` Ok. And your code is in?

Comment: Please tell what your code should do.

Comment: `pdf, and saving it to the external storage. ` For that you dont have to mess around with manage external storage.

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore, the permission below was missing

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: This is a missing information of your question. Please edit your question and do not provide missing information as answer.